# Rest end point's POST method not working in client (python) but same rest api works with soapUI

Tags: python, rest, post, urllib2, httplib

Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
I am currently integrating a REST based web services into my program. The REST services are tested with soapUI. All the REST end points are working fine. But when we integrate the REST services into python based client program we are facing issue with POST request. I have tried using urllib2, requests, httplib modules..

**urllib2 implementation**

```
import urllib2

import urllib

url = "https://serverip.com/webapi/object1/"
values = {
        "owner": 1,
        "parent": 1,
        "region": 7,
        "pod_identifier": "EMEMASTER1",
        "type": "S",
        "number": 1,
        "description": "TESTTTTT",
    }



data  = urllib.urlencode(values)

req = urllib2.Request(url)

req.add_data(data)
req.add_header("Authorization", "Token as123131231231312312321asddasd43532y5456#$%#$")

response = urllib2.urlopen(req)
res = response.read()
print res
```

**Result**

```
File "tester.py", line 24, in <module>
    response = urllib2.urlopen(req)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/urllib2.py", line 126, in urlopen
    return _opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/urllib2.py", line 397, in open
    response = meth(req, response)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/urllib2.py", line 510, in http_response
    'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/urllib2.py", line 435, in error
    return self._call_chain(*args)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/urllib2.py", line 369, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/urllib2.py", line 518, in http_error_default
    raise HTTPError(req.get_full_url(), code, msg, hdrs, fp)
urllib2.HTTPError: HTTP Error 400: BAD REQUEST
```

I am facing the same issue while using requests and httplib2 but the soapUI request works fine.

Can anyone help me to understand the problem?

/Shan

Comment: The problem is on the server, for some reason it doesn't like the data you are sending it. Do you have access to the server logs? Why does it consider the request a bad request?

Comment: Also if you can install third party Python librarys (ie you have access to easy_install or pip) use Requests rather than Urllib, much nicer to work with - http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/

Comment: I was able to make it work by just adding the urlencoded values to the url as query string like below...                              url = "https://serverip.com/webapi/object1/?%s" % data

Comment: Either Urllib isn't sending a POST (I hate the way Urllib guesses if you want a GET or a POST) or your server is only accepting GET requests. Try with Requests library instead of Urllib, where you tell it use get or post and see if posts work. If not then problem is probably on server

Comment: I have verified the method in the urllib request. It is POST only. Also if I remove the  """ req.add_data(data)  """ then the request becomes GET and retrieves all the object. The same error happns in python Requests library too. I will have to dig more to find out the problem... @Cormac Thanks for your suggestion...

Comment: No problem. Sounds like it is a server issue then, might only be expecting GET requests. Hope you get it working